# Every time I try to implement gravity to a sprite in Love2d, it breaks another feature,

Tags: lua, game-physics, game-development, gravity, love2d

Im trying to give the player for a game im working on gravity when its not climbing a ladder,
but every time i try to implement this feature, something climbing ladders breaks, and when i try to fix it, gravity breaks, or the other way around.

I've tried using just plain x and y, I've tried DX and DY, I've even tried ChatGpt, it wasn't able to figure it out. There's not an error, more a bug

my code is

```
-- Initialize the game
function love.load()
    -- Set the window dimensions
    love.window.setMode(800, 600)
    
    -- Set the title of the window
    love.window.setTitle("Mappy")
    
    -- Load the game assets
    characterImage = love.graphics.newImage("mappy.png")
    itemImage = love.graphics.newImage("item.png")
    enemyImage = love.graphics.newImage("enemy.png")
    
    -- Check if the image files loaded successfully
    if not characterImage or not itemImage or not enemyImage then
        error("Failed to load game assets. Make sure the image files exist and are accessible.")
    end
    
    -- Set the character's initial position
    characterX = 400
    characterY = love.graphics.getHeight() - 180
    
    -- Set the item's initial position
    itemX = 100
    itemY = 100
    
    -- Set the enemy's initial position
    enemyX = 700
    enemyY = 500
    
    -- Create a map
    map = {
        "#################################",
        "#                               #",
        "#         ^           ^         #",
        "#   ##### ^ ######### ^ #####   #",
        "#         ^           ^         #",
        "#         ^           ^         #",
        "#   ##### ^ ######### ^ #####   #",
        "#         ^           ^         #",
        "#         ^           ^         #",
        "#   ##### ^ ######### ^ #####   #",
        "#         ^           ^         #",
        "#         ^           ^         #",
        "#   ##### ^ ######### ^ #####   #",
        "#         ^           ^         #",
        "#         ^           ^         #",
        "#################################",
    }
    
    -- Set the tile size
    tileSize = 32
    
    -- Set up the camera
    camera = {
        x = 0,
        y = 0
    }
    
    -- Set initial ladder interaction state
    touchingLadder = false
end

-- Update the game state
function love.update(dt)
    -- Move the character based on user input
    local dx, dy = 0, 0
    if love.keyboard.isDown("up") and touchingLadder then
        dy = -200
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("down") and touchingLadder then
        dy = 200
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
        dx = -200
    end
    if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
        dx = 200
    end
    
    -- Check for collision with walls
    local wallCollision = checkWallCollision(characterX + dx * dt, characterY + dy * dt, characterImage:getWidth(), characterImage:getHeight())
    
    -- Move the character only if there is no collision with walls
    if not wallCollision then
        characterX = characterX + dx * dt
        characterY = characterY + dy * dt
    end
    
    -- Update the camera position to follow the character
    camera.x = characterX - love.graphics.getWidth() / 2
    camera.y = characterY - love.graphics.getHeight() / 2
    
    -- Check for collision between character and item
    if checkCollision(characterX, characterY, characterImage:getWidth(), characterImage:getHeight(),
                      itemX, itemY, itemImage:getWidth(), itemImage:getHeight()) then
        -- Respawn the item at a new random position
        itemX = love.math.random(100, 700)
        itemY = love.math.random(100, 500)
    end
    
    -- Check for collision between character and enemy
    if checkCollision(characterX, characterY, characterImage:getWidth(), characterImage:getHeight(),
                      enemyX, enemyY, enemyImage:getWidth(), enemyImage:getHeight()) then
        -- Game over
        love.event.quit()
    end
    
    -- Update ladder interaction state
    touchingLadder = checkLadderCollision(characterX, characterY, characterImage:getWidth(), characterImage:getHeight())
end

-- Draw the game state
function love.draw()
    -- Set the drawing transformation based on the camera position
    love.graphics.push()
    love.graphics.translate(-camera.x, -camera.y)
    
    -- Draw the map
    for y = 1, #map do
        local row = map[y]
        for x = 1, #row do
            local char = row:sub(x, x)
            if char == "#" then
                love.graphics.rectangle("fill", (x - 1) * tileSize, (y - 1) * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize)
            elseif char == "^" then
                love.graphics.rectangle("line", (x - 1) * tileSize, (y - 1) * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize)
            end
        end
    end
    
    -- Draw the character
    love.graphics.draw(characterImage, characterX, characterY)
    
    -- Draw the item
    love.graphics.draw(itemImage, itemX, itemY)
    
    -- Draw the enemy
    love.graphics.draw(enemyImage, enemyX, enemyY)
    
    -- Reset the drawing transformation
    love.graphics.pop()
end

-- Check collision between two rectangles
function checkCollision(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2)
    return x1 < x2 + w2 and
           x2 < x1 + w1 and
           y1 < y2 + h2 and
           y2 < y1 + h1
end

-- Check collision with walls
function checkWallCollision(x, y, width, height)
    -- Calculate the character's bounding box
    local characterLeft = x
    local characterRight = x + width
    local characterTop = y
    local characterBottom = y + height
    
    -- Check for collision with walls
    for y = 1, #map do
        local row = map[y]
        for x = 1, #row do
            local char = row:sub(x, x)
            if char == "#" then
                local wallLeft = (x - 1) * tileSize
                local wallRight = x * tileSize
                local wallTop = (y - 1) * tileSize
                local wallBottom = y * tileSize
                
                -- Check if the character's bounding box intersects with the wall
                if characterRight > wallLeft and characterLeft < wallRight and
                   characterBottom > wallTop and characterTop < wallBottom then
                    return true
                end
            end
        end
    end
    
    return false
end

-- Check collision with ladders
function checkLadderCollision(x, y, width, height)
    -- Calculate the character's bounding box
    local characterLeft = x
    local characterRight = x + width
    local characterTop = y
    local characterBottom = y + height
    
    -- Check for collision with ladders
    for y = 1, #map do
        local row = map[y]
        for x = 1, #row do
            local char = row:sub(x, x)
            if char == "^" then
                local ladderLeft = (x - 1) * tileSize
                local ladderRight = x * tileSize
                local ladderTop = (y - 1) * tileSize
                local ladderBottom = y * tileSize
                
                -- Check if the character's bounding box intersects with the ladder
                if characterRight > ladderLeft and characterLeft < ladderRight and
                   characterBottom > ladderTop and characterTop < ladderBottom then
                    return true
                end
            end
        end
    end
    
    return false
end
```

Comment: The example you've posted does not contain any code dealing with gravity, and seems to be in a functional state. Please post the non-working code here, preferably in a proper [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which means removing anything that is not required to reproduce the issue (here that is probably anything to do with the *enemy* and the *item*).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The whole main.lua is OK - Because it have to run in LÖVE - If you provide only a little peace of Code then it will not run and will not produce the same error in LÖVE - I suggest to provide the PNG Pictures too - Because without them it is even not reproduceable.